# Backbone JOIN Collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность объединять модели разных коллекций по определенным атрибутам в одну коллекцию?

Ищу аналог операции `JOIN` в SQL, где можно указать таблицы и поля, по которым данные связываются.

Например, есть 2 коллекции Backbone: `Children` и `Parents`. У каждой модели в `Parents` есть `ID`, у каждой модели `Children` есть `PARENT_ID`. Необходимо связать эти коллекции по атрибутам `ID` и `PARENT_ID` соответственно, чтобы в результате получить коллекцию модели которой будут содержать в себе атрибуты моделей обеих коллекций.
Попытаюсь показать на таком примере:

```
//Эти коллекции существуют, берутся из БД
var Child = Backbone.Model.extend({
    id: some_id,
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2,
    parent_id: some_parent_id
});

var Children = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Child 
});

var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    id: some_parent_id,
    prop3: prop3,
    prop4: prop4,
});

var Parents = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Parent 
});

// Эту нужно получить программно из двух имеющихся
var Result = Backbone.Model.extend({
    id: some_id,
    parent_id: some_parent_id
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2,
    prop3: prop3,
    prop4: prop4,
});    

var Results = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать модель, которая унаследуется от Parent (или сделать так чтобы Child наследовался от Parent если необходимо)

```
var Result = Parent.extend({
  id: some_id,
  parent_id: some_parent_id
  prop1: prop1,
  prop2: prop2
});
```

Для автоматизации преднаполнения модели данными можно переопределить конструктор:

```
constructor: function(parent_id) {
  var pt = Parents.findWhere({id: parent_id})
  this.prop3 = pt.prop3;
  this.prop4 = pt.prop4;
  Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Далее по аналогии как Вам удобно: можете запросить данные Child-модели с сервера или вытащить из коллекции Children